Proof that the Yoneda embedding is cartesian closed
Is there a reference somewhere that the Yoneda embedding is cartesian closed? I tried showing this myself, but after staring at it for an afternoon, I did not yet see a proof. I saw an answer here giving an isomorphism (which should also be shown to be natural) between $ Y(A)^{Y(B)}(c) $ and $ Y(A^B)(c) $. Does this also show that the Yoneda embedding satisfies the definition of 'cartesian closed functor' given on nlab, or do we need a different proof for that? (If so, how do we show that?)

You need to unfold the proof and check that the isomorphism is indeed the canonical morphism, and of course you need to prove Yoneda preserves products, but other than that it's good.

@Trebor More like, Yoneda unfold the proof
